# Angular 12 Http headers not added

Tags: angular

I try to add Auth header for request:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.user.token}`
  })
};
return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/api/exchange/producers`, request, httpOptions);
```

But the header is not added to the request. Where a mistake?

Comment: Can you provide the imports you are using for `this.http` and `HttpHeaders`?

Comment: @Alejandro Barone updated

Comment: what is the type of `this.http`? is it HttpClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting directly to the object?:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
 .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.user.token}`);

return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/api/exchange/producers`, request, { headers });
```

Also, if necessary, you can use a `HTTP_INTERCEPTOR` if you need to inject this header on multiple requests to avoid copy and pasting code.